# Android CameraX: how to get AF status associated with an analysis ImageProxy

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I'm new to CameraX, coming from Camera2

With Camera2, when CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.onCaptureCompleted is called, we get an instance of TotalCaptureResult which contains many useful information about the image, for instance:
`final Integer afState = result.get(TotalCaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);`

Now, I'm starting to use CameraX, with an ImageAnalysis UseCase.

In that case, I receive the image through

```
void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image);
```

But then, how could I get the autofocus status associated with the image?

Thanks a lot

I searched CameraX source code without finding an answer.

But for a use case such analyze, that seems to me very important to know if the image is in focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps someone else, I found a solution to my question.

In summary, use Camera2Interop.Extender(builder)

For details, at the place where I was using ImageAnalysis.Builder(), I modify it with an implementation of CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback which belongs to Camera2, back into the known world where you can get metadata about each image like this:

```
val result: CaptureResult
val afState result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE)
```

Here is how I get the CaptureResult:

```
val builder = ImageAnalysis.Builder()  
Camera2Interop.Extender(builder).setSessionCaptureCallback(captureCallback)
val analysisUseCase = builder.build()
```

where `captureCallback` implements `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback`

Then you just have to use timestamp to map capture metadata with each image:

- `imageProxy.imageInfo.timestamp` that you get from your implementation of

```
ImageAnalysis.Analyzer.analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy)
```

- `result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP)` that you get from your implementation of

```
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.onCaptureCompleted(
        session: CameraCaptureSession,
        request: CaptureRequest,
        result: TotalCaptureResult
)
```

But be careful with the fact that `onCaptureCompleted` is not necessarily called for each image that is provided to `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer.analyze`.